# Custom ErrorMessage for Compare attribute does not work

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, compare-attribute

Steps to reproduce:

1. Create a new MVC 5 project with Individual User Accounts.
2. Look at the `ErrorMessage` specified in `RegisterViewModel` for the `ConfirmPassword` property. It is "The password and confirmation password do not match.".
3. Build and run the application, and try to register with non-matching passwords. I'll se the error message "'Confirm password' and 'Password' do not match.", instead of the one specified in the model.

It seems like a custom `ErrorMessage` property on the `Compare` attribute isn't working. Even if I specify a ErrorMessage, the validation still shows some sort of default message instead.

This work with `System.Web.Mvc.CompareAttribute`, but this is now **deprecated** and you should instead use `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.CompareAttribute`, which shows this problem.

I add the `Compare` attribute to a property and specify the `ErrorMessage` as follows:

```
[Compare("NewPassword", ErrorMessage = "The new password and confirmation password do not match. I'll even add some random text!")]
public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
```

the expected result would be (**but this isn't what I get**):

[image: Expected result with custom ErrorMessage]

Instead, I get this "default" error message:

[image: Actual result with standard ErrorMessage]

Client side validation is disabled. Am I missing something? This example is taken from the MVC 5 template with Individual User Accounts as authentication.

Comment: Why are you sure it's disabled? And how it's related to the result you are expecting?

Comment: I assume you mean client side validation? I've changed the web.config to `<add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="false" />` and if I check the Net panel in my developer tool I can see the postback, and the error message in the response HTML.

Comment: So, what's the problem? You say that you've added the validation, you expect it to be as on the picture, but you are not happy with that.

Comment: I show a picture of **how** I expect it to be. What I get is shown on the picture below, which isn't what I expect. I will clarify that.

Comment: I think you did not search well, the same question were [here][1]
Let me know if that was helpful.

  [1]: http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/4938078/using-dataannotations-to-compare-two-model-properties

Comment: @NativeBasic As you can see I **am** using that solution (although not the `Compare` from `System.Web.Mvc` since it deprecated) but it doesn't wok the way I would expect. And yes, I did search.

Comment: I am not sure what's the issue: you should provide then all the details on your views, controllers and modesl, I guess. I tried the both way: with client or server validations and both work well with a correct message. (Try to build the app from scratch and then compare what's the difference (if the "scratch" works). Also, you may have a look at this (not sure if that might be related to depricated infrastructure): http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/727650/system-web-mvc-compare-ambiguous-reference-exception

Comment: @Agat Thanks for your input. However, I just tried to create a new MVC5 project with VS2013 and the issues appears. I've edited my post to describe what I did and how I tried it. The link you provided points to use the deprecated `System.Web.Mvc.CompareAttribute`, which is the deprecated one I'm trying to get away from. (All other attributes used in MVC nowadays is in `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations`, so I'd like to use the Compare attribute from there as well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think this is a bug. (Edit: It is.)  I'm also able to reproduce this.  In fact, the behaviour is exactly the same with client-side validation turned on.  If you take a look at the generated HTML, you'll see it's not even generating the custom error string - it always emits the default one.

Actually, I've just had a search around to find more information and I've found it has been submitted as a bug on codeplex.  It was reported 8 days ago and someone has been assigned to it.  You can find the bug report [here](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/1401).

Comment: Seems like my Google-fu failed me a bit then, but thanks a lot for finding the bug report!

Comment: @JLe No problem. :) Just a shame it's not what you wanted to hear.

Answer (score 16):

I have same problem, solution:

Change:

```
[Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
```

To:

```
[System.Web.Mvc.Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
```

It's working!

Comment: Yeah I know, but that seems like a bad workaround since `System.Web.Mvc.Compare` is deprecated.

Answer (score 7):

It's an [old bug](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/1401) from 2013. Try the following command to update all of the [project's dependencies](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc/):

```
PM> update-package
```