# How do I properly use DataAnnotations to register users with Identity in .NET 5.0?

Tags: .net, entity-framework, asp.net-identity, registration, .net-5

I'm trying to create a registration with Identity in a .NET 5.0 MVC and I'm having problems with my Annotations, especially `Compare` and `Required` in my ViewModel. Submitting with an empty email field will reload the page, same with an invalid PW (6 chars, 1 special, 1 num, 1 capital). Submitting with an empty pw field causes a crash in the controller POST route when it tries to use a null pw in `CreateAsync()`.

Any help is appreciated.

Here is my ViewModel

```cs
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace Test.ViewModels
{
    public class RegisterViewModel
    {
        [Required]                      // doesn't seem to work
        [EmailAddress]                  // this works
        [Display(Name = "Email")]       // works
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [Required]                     // doesn't work
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]  // doesn't seem to do anything
        [Display(Name = "Password")]   // works
        public string Password { get; set; }

        [Required]                          // doesn't work
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]       // doesn't seem to do anything
        [Display(Name = "Confirm password")] // works
        [Compare(nameof(Password), ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")] // doesn't work
//      [Compare("Password")]  also doesn't work
        public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
    }
}
```

here is my View

```html
@using Test.ViewModels
@model RegisterViewModel

<h2>Register a new user</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Register", "Account"))
{
    @Html.LabelFor(user => user.Email)
    @Html.EditorFor(user => user.Email)

    @Html.LabelFor(user => user.Password)
    @Html.PasswordFor(user => user.Password)

    @Html.LabelFor(user => user.ConfirmPassword)
    @Html.PasswordFor(user => user.ConfirmPassword)

    <input type="submit" value="Register" />
}
```

Here is the controller post action

```cs
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Register (RegisterViewModel model)
        {
            var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email };
            IdentityResult result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            else
            {
                return View();
            }
        }
```

I've tried these other hits for SO answers on this and I haven't found a solution in them, maybe because they are 7-10 years old.

[Using DataAnnotations to compare two model properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4938078/using-dataannotations-to-compare-two-model-properties)

[Email address validation using ASP.NET MVC data type attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16712043/email-address-validation-using-asp-net-mvc-data-type-attributes) - this one helped solve a problem with `[EmailAddress]`, I was using the wrong HTML Helper so it wasn't validating the input.

Comment: check this tutorial and let me know if it is helpful. https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/ASPNet-MVC-Client-Side-validations-using-Data-Annotation-attributes-and-jQuery.aspx and https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/mvc/implement-validation-in-asp.net-mvc

Comment: Yes, with your second link I was able to find the missing steps needed to make this work, specifically this article was a great help: https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/mvc/htmlhelper-validationsummary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was in a link posted by @mohammad-mobasher, and [this link](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/mvc/htmlhelper-validationsummary) was very helpful.

What I was missing was using `@Html.ValidationSummary(false)` in my view and wrapping the code in my POST route with `if (ModelState.IsValid){}`. `@Html.ValidationSummary(false)` checks for validation on the ViewModel properties and will add an unordered list with any violations to the register page *if* the the form is submitted and the model state is not valid.

The change to the controller looks like this:

```cs
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
{
  if (ModelState.IsValid) // this is new
  {
    ApplicationUser user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email };
    IdentityResult result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
    if (result.Succeeded)
    {
      return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
  }
  return View(model);
}
```

and the view:

```
@using Test.ViewModels
@model RegisterViewModel

<h2>Register a new user</h2>
<hr />
@using (Html.BeginForm("Register", "Account", FormMethod.Post))
{
  @Html.LabelFor(user => user.Email)
  @Html.TextBoxFor(user => user.Email)   
  <!-- changed back to TextBoxFor, now the Validation method works for this -->


  @Html.LabelFor(user => user.Password)
  @Html.PasswordFor(user => user.Password)

  @Html.LabelFor(user => user.ConfirmPassword)
  @Html.PasswordFor(user => user.ConfirmPassword)

  <input type="submit" value="Register" />
}

<!-- added this -->
@Html.ValidationSummary(false)
```